# Storing date-time values

Tags: android, sqlite, datetime, android-sqlite

From [this link](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) I read that the best data type for storing date-time values in SQLite is `INTEGER`.

What is the best format that should be used to store the current date and time into said attribute?
`SimpleDateFormat` only accepts Strings, yet the datatype is `INTEGER`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could store the time in milliseconds. Retrieve the `Date` object from the SimpleDateFormat and the equivalent value in ms `long milliseconds = date.getTime ();`. Store `milliseconds`

Comment: Would that save the date as well ?

Comment: you can rebuild the Date from the milliseconds

Comment: But be aware that you lose the UTC timezone in that regard and that those are not interchangeable.